# The tag badge I just received still appears in the recommended badges to track

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

I just earned a bronze tag badge for [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file):

[image: File badge earned]

Naturally, I proceeded to click "Track the next one", which suggested that I pursue the "file" tag, and try to get a bronze badge for it...

[image: File suggested]

I presume it's [another caching issue](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), but I'm reporting it here on the off chance it's an actual bug in the badge suggestion dialog.